# Sharded MongoDB environment and spring mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have been learning mongodb integration with spring for past 2-3 days and have got a question.

In a sharded enviroment, where we have multiple shards , each shard containing multiple replicas everything is handled by mongos process and end application does not have to be changed if a new shard is added. Am I correct?

**Question:**

I could see some configurations related to replica-set in spring-context.xml which have caused me to think.
Why do we need to tell spring about replica set if everything is taken care of by mongos process?